# Android listview with alternate items in each row

Tags: android, android-listview

android listview with first row left side image and right side text, second row just opposite of first row.. Can any one help me with an example code?Or is it Possible in listview?

Comment: Dear you creat row.xml file and take two image view and two text view left and right as you want and in your activity you mange even and odd position and set visibility of image view and text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do alternative items like below

```
    row.xml
    <RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>

//In Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
    if(position%2==0)
    {
    //left side image and right side text
    img2.setImgResource();
    img2.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
    txt2.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
    img1.setVisibility(VIEW.VISABLE);
    txt1.setVisibility(VIEW.VISABLE);
    txt2.setText();
    }
    else
    {
    //left side text and right side image code

    img2.setImgResource();
    img1.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
    txt1.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
    img2.setVisibility(VIEW.VISABLE);
    txt2.setVisibility(VIEW.VISABLE);
    txt2.setText();
    }
    }
```